# How to get location name from coordinates in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I wanted a button that can get the location of the user and display the place name using GPS.

I tried [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) but it only can get latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use the [geocoder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geocoder)  plugin 
it provide you a [findAddressesFromCoordinates](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/geocoder/0.0.1/services_base/Geocoding/findAddressesFromCoordinates.html)

> import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

example;

```
final coordinates = new Coordinates(1.10, 45.50);
addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
first = addresses.first;
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
```

**NOTE:**
you can also use [geolocation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocation) plugin to get a lot of useful information like Retrieving last known location

Comment: Throws missing plugin exception

Comment: please post your problem in another question

Comment: One simple question i have. Is there any limit of requests for Geocoder?

Comment: if we only need the city name then

Comment: @SohaibAslam: If we only need the city name then ?? Did you find the answer ?

Comment: @Pawan yes I find it.

Comment: You need to do a hot reload to get away with the missing plugin exception

Comment: @RaoufRahiche Is there any free service to use map address to lat-long, lat-long to address and place autocomplete provider? Kindly suggest. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use geocoding package available on the pub.dev
the rest of the packages are deprecated and also don't support null safety

1. get coordinates from the address:
   List locations = await locationFromAddress("Gronausestraat 710, Enschede");
2. get the address from coordinates:
   List placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

Just create an object like `LocationService locationService = LocationService();` and call the function `getLocationPermission()` and chain `getAddress()` to get the address like below.

As the funcion name says this code handels the location permission to the devide too.

```
locationService.getLocationPermission().then((dataMap) {
  // print(dataMap.toString());
  if (dataMap["hasError"]) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        sb5Sec(textContent: Text(dataMap["eMsg"].toString())));
  } else {
    // Call get location name
    locationService
        .getAddress(
            lat: dataMap["data"]["latitude"],
            lon: dataMap["data"]["longitude"])
        .then((addressMap) {
      // print(">> from init " + addressMap["data"]);
      locationTEC.text = addressMap["data"];
    });
  }
});
```

You can get the source code in >> [LocationService.dart GitHub](https://github.com/rajathirumal/personal/blob/master/lib/services/location_service.dart)

Find how it is used in >> [github.com/rajathirumal](https://github.com/rajathirumal/personal)