# How to get city from coordinates in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, maps

I am using [GeoLocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) dependency on Flutter and able to get the real-time coordinates of the location.

But I want only generalized coordinates of the city to be derived how should I do that.

The below code is providing exact realtime location when using the above mentioned dependency, which I don't require.

I want to have the city name based on the geolocation.

Please guide how should I achieve it?

```
 await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition().then((value) => {
                        _positionItems.add(_PositionItem(
                            _PositionItemType.position, value.toString()))
                      });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get location name from coordinates in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756133/how-to-get-location-name-from-coordinates-in-flutter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Geocoding https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


...
position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5))
 
try {
    List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude,
        position.longitude,
      );
      print(placemarks[0]);
      ...
    }catch(err){}
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder

```
var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
String yourCityName = address.first.locality
```

Comment: Not works anymore?

Comment: Package is not updated anymore... try the other answer by Max

Answer (score 0):

Geodecoder is deprecated in Dart 3, instead of Geodecoder, use Geocode as follows:

```
var address = await GeoCode().reverseGeocoding(latitude, longitude);
```

Now you can find more things by using the variable address:

```
 print(address.city);
```

print(address.countryName);

[Link for Geocode](https://pub.dev/packages/geocode)